# Start and stop action_hooks not firing in openshift online PHP 5.3

Tags: openshift

I am trying to fire an action every time a new gear is added to a scalable app and when a gear is destroyed (no longer needed).

I thought it would be "start" and "stop", but nothing seems to happen... 
I have also tried start_Php-5.3, and start_cartridge with no success...

The deploy hook fires and writes to the new gear's log (not app-root), but none of the start/stop hooks seem to work...

Where am I supposed to put my commands?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are marking your start & stop scripts as executable (`chmod +x`) before you add them to your git repository and do a git push.  Check out this page for more information about build hooks: https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications

Comment: Yes, i did mark them +x and git push... Cron works - same script, but not start nor stop...